# How can I fork and keep just the number of processes I need?

Tags: linux, process, fork

Suppose I want to create 3 processes and I for 3 times, I am going to have 7 processes. I just want to keep 3 processes other than the original parent process. Is there any way to do it? I have to use `fork()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fork in the parent three times, and  you end up with a process chart like this:

```
        parent
 _________|_________
 |        |        |
c1        c2       c3
```

Fork, check if you're in the parent, if you are fork again, repeat.

To do this for *n* processes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if(!fork()) {
    //In child
    break;
    //Child code
  }
}
```

Comment: ok that works for three processes, but is there any way to apply it to  k number of processes? Thank you very much.